# Getting text value when a list is clicked - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which is being loaded from a php file I am trying to get text inside this list. When i click this list, the console gives me a referenceError. I am going to show just HTML code with comments where data is added from php.

```
<div data-demo-html="true">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-split-theme="b" data-split-icon="plus" data-inset="true" id="courselist">
    <!-- Data below loaded from PHP-->
    <li id="clist">
    <a href="#page">
    <h2> text loaded here </h2>
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Data loading finished from PHP -->
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
var desc;
$('body').on('click','clist',function(){
    desc = $(this).text();
    console.log(desc);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong as `clist` is `id` of `li` element, so use `'#clist'` instead of `'clist'`:

```
<script>
$(function(){
var desc;
$('body').on('click','#clist',function(){
    desc = $(this).text();
    console.log(desc);
});
});
</script>
```

See **[jQuery Selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** for more information

Answer (score 0):

You missed id # selector

HTML `<li id="clist">`

```
 $('body').on('click','#clist',function(){
                      ^^^^^
                  desc = $(this).text();
            console.log(desc);
        });
```

Read Jquery **[Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**